# Using Javascript Variables as WP_Query Parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm having some problems attempting to use a Javascript variable as a WordPress Query parameter.

I'm sending an Javascript array of `post_ids` to Wordpress using an AJAX Post Request.

`$.post('url', { data: requestIds }, function(response) { console.log(response) });`

I'm basically trying to pass the Javascript array of 'requestIds' as the `post__in` WP_Query parameter.

```
$COMPARISON_QUERY = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array('Post'),
    'post__in' => // this is where the array would be passed as a parameter
));
```

Here's the PHP that handles the request:

```
$response_object = DecodeJSONString($_POST['data']);

function DecodeJSONString($string) {
    $decoded_string = json_decode($string);
    return $decoded_string; // this would be the query parameter
}
```

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: So what problems are you having??

Comment: Well, in order to use the WP_Query I need to include the following: define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
However, doing so breaks the json_decode function making the value of the array 'NULL'. Meaning when I attempt to use it as a parameter, I'm just passing NULL as post__in.

Comment: please just `var_dump($_POST)` and edit your question to show the output - possibly you are sending regular key value pairs, not json

Comment: http://pastie.org/10615941#1,6,20 That pastie shows 3 responses, with and without the wp-load and a var_dump of the $_POST['data'].

Comment: Thanks Connor - could you confirm if the var_dump output is for when define and require lines are included or not? It seems pretty odd that your function would break - but perhaps there is already a function with that name - could you try just calling `json_decode` directly?

Comment: @Steve, I'm prepending 'PHP Response' to the response so the response for the var_dump with the define and require included is 'NULL'.  If I do this, with the define and require included I get a response or absolutely nothing... 0 length. http://pastie.org/10615963

Comment: Curious. If you comment everything, leaving only the following:`define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); require_once('../../../wp-load.php');echo 'post data: ';var_dump($_POST);` what do you see?

Comment: Never ever ever ever use `require_once('../../../wp-load.php')` This has been such a chewed up topic that it should be stickied somewhere: http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/
http://ottopress.com/2010/passing-parameters-from-php-to-javascripts-in-plugins/

Comment: @Steve This is the output from your suggestion.

`data: array(1) {
  ["data"]=>
  string(32) "[\"5\",\"8\",\"6\",\"9\",\"11\"]"
}`

Comment: Ok, how about `define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); require_once('../../../wp-load.php');echo 'post data: ';var_dump(json_decode($_POST['data']));`

Comment: if you see `array(5) {
  [0] =>
  string(1) "5"
  [1] =>
  string(1) "8"
  [2] =>
  string(1) "6"
  [3] =>
  string(1) "9"
  [4] =>
  string(2) "11"
}` Then the problem is elsewhere - as the data is clearly being sent and decoded fine

Comment: @Steve, I've found that it works perfectly... as long as require_once and json_decode are not being used together.

Comment: That makes no sense at all - `json_decode` cannot be modified by user code - it is possible that `$_POST` data can be modified, but that doesnt appear to be the case

Comment: @Steve, Perhaps my entire approach is wrong? I'm trying to get certain posts based on IDS which are generated client sided with javascript, e.g. If I have a big collection of Posts, but I want to 'mark to read' 4 posts and when I click 'read marked' it will return the current 'marked to read' posts based on a client sided cookie which holds all the selected 'the_IDS();' of each marked post.

Comment: Its too hard to help when i only know little bits of code - if you could show the whole php section, along with the javascipt, then i might be able to spot the issue

Comment: What URL are you posting to? As @dingo_d said, you shouldn't be including wp-load.php, you should be posting to admin-ajax.php

Comment: @Chizzle I'm posting to PHP file which then manipulates the request data using `$_POST['val']` What does `admin-ajax.php` do with the request?

Comment: @Connor try using the method I posted below. It looks like a lot but honestly all it really should be for you is hooking up the ajax url in your javascript, setting up a handler in functions.php and then including your existing php script - minus the includes for other wp files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of posting to your php file that does the work directly, you should be doing your ajax requests using [WordPress ajax functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Say the custom php file you are using is called `process_post.php`. Instead of posting to your custom php file directly, post to `admin-ajax.php` and handle the post in your `functions.php` file.

On your front end page:

```
<script>
    var ajaxUrl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>"; // This will get the approriate ajax url using wordpress functionality
    $.post(  ajaxUrl, 
         { 
            'action': 'my_action',
            'requestIds': requestIds // Assuming you have your requestIds var populated already 
         },
         function(response) {
           console.log(response)
         });
</script>
```

Now on the php side there is a kind of tricky/unintuitive part about registering your ajax action `my_action`. It's a naming convention where you append the action name `my_action` after `wp_ajax` and `wp_ajax_no_priv`. Note, you wouldn't hook up your action to `wp_ajax_no_priv` if regular users aren't supposed to touch it.

The first argument is the naming convention, the second argument is your custom function name:

```
<?php // in functions.php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
?>
```

Now you have your ajax action set up! Now create your callback function, also in `functions.php`. I often just include the separate php file from this point like this:

```
<?php // Still in functions.php
function my_action_callback(){
    include_once('my_code.php');
}
?>
```

**Now that you have set all this up properly you no longer need to include different core WordPress classes!** That is the main reason of going through all the hassle of setting it up this way.

In  `my_code.php` which would reside in your theme in my example:

```
<?php
$COMPARISON_QUERY = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array('Post'),
    'post__in' => json_decode( $_POST['requestIds'] ),
));
```

Comment: Thank you! I managed to fix my problem in a very similar method to the one you posted above! Although, I had to localize my ajaxurl because I was working directly from a .js file. This video was incredibly helpful, so for future people having this issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d01I9n8mbOU